Как получить только самые новые события из admin log?
Написал небольшой код используя telethon, этот код вытягивает ВСЕ события бана участника, а мне нужно только самые новые события, как это можно реализовать?
Вот мой код:
async def get_admin_log(channel_id: int, msg: Message):
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in client.iter_admin_log(channel_id):
            channel_info = await get_channel_info(channel_id)

            if isinstance(event.action, ChannelAdminLogEventActionParticipantToggleBan):
                banned_user_id = event.action.new_participant.peer.user_id
    
                if banned_user_id == bot.id:
                    await msg.answer(f"Вы отлкючили бота в канале {channel_info['title']}")
                    await delete_channels_from_db(channel_id)
                    run = False
                else:
                    print("нет")```

